# How to add Shiro SessionListener when Shiro is used with Spring and web filter?

Tags: security, shiro

I want to add a session listener (`org.apache.shiro.session.SessionListener`) to `SessionManager`. As I found out when shiro web is used then by default the implementation of `SessionManager` is `ServletContainerSessionManager`. However, I didn't find any methods to add listeners in `ServletContainerSessionManager`. Could anyone say how to add this listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ServletContainerSessionManager` is just a wrapper around the session management your Servlet container provides. If you want to use Shiro's `SessionListner` you would need to use a different `SessionManager` implementation, such as `DefaultWebSessionManager`